# Repeating section or binding?

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath

I am having a hardtime with InfoPath... So basically, I have built a form with repeating sections from a sharepoint list. However, I want both repeating and non repeating section. When I fill out my form on sharepoint, I am annoyed by this little square. This section should be a non repeating section and so I want to get rid of this blue square. Can someone help me please? :)

[image: I got this screenshot from my sharepointlist, when I fill out the form]

Answer (score 0):

In InfoPath form, we can add “Section” and “Repeating Section”, if you don’t want to use repeat section for only a field, you can insert a section and relevant control, then edit this control’s properties, set the default value with the relevant field of secondary connection.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately when you create a custom list **App** on Sharepoint and you want to customize the form with InfoPath, it doesn't allow you to choose different types of containers but only **Section** that have the repeating parameter. [image]
[image: ]]
I would like to change this repeating section into a non-repeating section but there is apparently no way
[image: I unchecked those 2 checkboxes but the blue arrow still appears the browser when I fill out the form]
I unchecked those 2 checkboxes but the blue arrow still appears the browser when I fill out the form